# with $location.search(): how to remove a parameter from the url when it's null

Tags: angularjs

`$location.search()` to set an url

the search parameter which is passed to the `search()` is set by a form. selecting and deselecting an element causes some parameters value to be "null" and so the url looks like this :

```
myapp.com/search?type=text&parameter=null
```

so i would like to remove those "null" parameters from the url. In the documentation, there is a "paramValue" which can be passed as a second parameters to .search(search, paramValue) : *If the value is `null`, the parameter will be deleted.*

but i can't make this work… any suggestion ?

**edit:** here is a solution based on @BKM explanation

to remove every parameters which are `null`, it's necessary to loop through all of them and test each one, like this :

```
for (var i in search) {
    if (!search[i]) $location.search(i, null);
}
$location.search(search);
```

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Using the `$location` service, you can remove the search param by assigning it a null value:

In the case when your parameter is null, in your case `'parameter'` you can remove it from the url by assigning it a null value like;

```
$location.search('parameter', null);
```

Comment: ok this is removing the parameter. so, to make what i wanted, i had to loop through every parameters and remove it if the parameter is null (`if (!parameter)`). thank you. i am going to edit my answer with this solution

Answer (score 31):

You can use `$location.search({})` to clear all at once.

Answer (score -1):

You can also do:

```
var search = $location.search();
if (search.parameter == 'null') {
  $location.search({'parameter': null});
}
```